# How to fix table header in Extjs 4.2

Tags: header, grid, fixed, extjs4.2

I want to fix my table/grid header in my ExtJs 4.2 application, so that the header is allways visible, while scroling. The main grid in my application has a fixed header and is implemented as in the code in the bottom of this post.
It is not working and I don't know why...
I tried it with the split attribute, but it isn't working, too... :(

This is the code:

```
function openThePopup() {
var win = new Ext.Window({
    modal : true,
    height : 500,
    width : 900,
    plain : true,
    border : false,
    resizable : false,
    maximizable : false,
    draggable : true,
    closable : true,
    closeAction : 'destroy',
    title : 'Title',
    autoScroll : true,
    buttonAlign : 'center',
    items : [ {
        xtype : 'grid',
        id : 'theGrid',
        store : theStore,
        border : 0,
        layout : 'fit',
        margins : '5 0 0 0',
        split : true,
        columns : [ {
            text : 'Country',
            dataIndex : 'country'
        }, {
            text : 'City',
            dataIndex : 'city'
        }, {
            text : 'ZIP',
            dataIndex : 'zip'
        }, {
            text : 'Street',
            dataIndex : 'street',
            width : 200
        }, {
            text : location,
            dataIndex : 'name',
            width : 200
        } ],
        listeners : {
            itemdblclick : function(t, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                ...
            }
        }
    } ],
    buttons : [ {
        onClick : function() {
            ...
        }
    } ]
}).show();
}
```

I appriciate any help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best wishes to all of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your layout isn't configured correctly. The `layout: 'fit'` should go on the window and the layout configuration should be removed from the grid. Also remove the `autoScroll` config on the window.

Comment: Hi Evan, I need the autoscroll but you are right with the layout. Now it's working properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: The autoScroll does not go on the window. By definition, the window cannot scroll, because it will size the child grid to exactly it's size. The grid is configured to scroll automatically. So, as I said above, the `autoScroll` on the window does nothing.

Comment: And again, you are completly right. It works exactly like you said. Thank you very much!